# What does "views" refer back to in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> They regarded excessive personal debt as a sin, **views** that widely and
>   firmly were held until relatively recently.

I wonder what is **"views"** referring back to in this sentence and whether this sentence is grammatically correct.

I think **"views"** referring back to **"Regarded excessive personal debt as a sin"** without **"they"**.

So, what I want to know is whether **"views"** includes **"they"** or not and what it's referring to exactly.

Comment: I think it's a poor construction. The fact that they regarded excessive personal debt as a sin looks to me like ***a** [single] **view*** (held by multiple people), so the plural form there doesn't work for me. Note that the *syntactic* link between the  noun ***a view*** and the preceding text that it refers to is inherently "loose". Compare, for example, *He hates foreigners, **an attitude** that most of his friends find embarrassing* (it's up to the reader to figure out that the statement ***he hates foreigners*** does indeed "represent" the corresponding noun phrase ***an attitude***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was, too, thinking that "views" seems to be strange and wrong where it's put, but as a non-native speaker, I just had to paste the original sentence here as I was not able to catch exactly whether it is wrong, though quite feeling it. Anyways, I think "a view" is referring back to "regarded excessive personal debt as a sin" without including "they". Do you think I am right? (I catch the point you're talking about in your comment, but I'm asking again to be sure whether I'm right.

Comment: You're right, SinK.  The "view" is "regarding excessive personal debt as a sin."

Comment: @Juhasz By the way, are you a Canadian native English speaker?

Comment: @SinK: I chose my words carefully when I said it's a "poor" construction. I think singular ***view*** is "better", but I wouldn't go so far as to say one version is "right" and the other "wrong". In closely-related contexts such as *His **view / views** on Brexit **is / are** well-known*, it really makes no difference whether we use singular or plural, ***regardless*** of whether the only opinion he actually has is just the (effectively, *singular*) perspective ***Brexit is a bad idea***.

Comment: I am a native American English speaker, @SinK.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I got your point. Btw, what's your view on my thinking that "view" is referring to "regarded .. a sin" without "they"? Judging by your comment, you seem to think "view" is referring to "They regarded excessive personal debt as a sin", but IMHO, this perspective doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: As @Juhasz said, *the "view" is "regarding excessive personal debt as a sin."* They fact that we're specifically told ***they*** hold that view isn't really relevant to the syntax. The word "view" would still refer to the same thing if we rephrased to, say, ***It was thought that** excessive personal debt is a sin, **a view** that [blah blah],* where whoever actually *had* that thought isn't even specified. But your example text has other issues that are more noticeably "wrong" than the ***view/views*** choice (*widely and firmly were held* is a ***very, very** poor* construction! :)

Comment: @Juhasz If the sentence is rewritten with "which is" as "They regarded excessive personal debt as a sin, which is a view that widely and firmly was held until relatively recently", is "which" referring back to "regarding excessive personal debt as a sin"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers If the sentence is rewritten with "which is" as "They regarded excessive personal debt as a sin, which is a view that widely and firmly was held until relatively recently", is "which" referring back to "regarding excessive personal debt as a sin"?

Comment: Please let me know guys.

Comment: *Syntactically*, that "which" refers back to ***the preceding statement itself** (They regarded excessive personal debt as a sin)*. But *semantically / logically* it refers to ***the action / attitude** (described by that statement)*. **This** simply reflects the flexibility of internal cross-references in English utterances (you might as well ask me to identify the specific "noun" that the first "**This**" refers to at the start of **this** sentence).

Comment: Consider the utterance *I cannot answer your question, unfortunately* where that last word is called a "sentence adverb" (it refers to / modifies the *entire sentence it's contained within*). By the same token, we could say that the highlighted word in *I cannot answer your question, **which** is unfortunate* is a kind of "sentence pronoun" (which refers to ***the fact that** I cannot answer*, rather than the assertion itself). That's a much "looser" link than that of the word "which" in the preceding sentence here, which obviously *exactly* refers to *[a kind of] "**sentence pronoun**"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is written in a confusing manner:

> They regarded excessive personal debt as a sin, views that widely and firmly were held until relatively recently.

It's confusing because it mixes the singular in the first part with the plural in the second part. (And *were* is in an awkward place.)

There are two possible ways of interpreting it.

---

**1. A single view.**

> They regarded excessive personal debt as a sin, **a view** that **was** widely and firmly held until relatively recently.

The *view* they all held: ***excessive personal debt is a sin***.

---

**2. Multiple views.**

> They **each** regarded excessive personal debt as a sin **in a different way**, views that were widely and firmly held **by them** until relatively recently.

The *views* they all held: ***different ways in which excessive personal debt is a sin***.

---

Note that in the original sentence, *regards* (from *regarded*) and *views* are synonymous:

> They ***regarded*** <sup>excessive personal debt as a sin</sup>, ***[regards]*** that widely and firmly were held until relatively recently.
>
> They ***[viewed]*** <sup>excessive personal debt as a sin</sup>, ***views*** that widely and firmly were held until relatively recently.

However, *regards* is not normally used in that way. If the two words weren't mixed, and a single form were to be chosen, it would sound better to use *viewed* and *views*.

Comment: To your way of thinking, does it seem not quite right to see "a view" as referring to "regarding xcessive personal debt as a sin"?

Comment: @SinK That's not the view. If it were, you would say this: *My view is that regarding personal debt as a sin . . .* ***[what?]*** It would be incomplete. Here, *view* and *regard* are synonyms. *I **view** it as a sin* and *I **regard** it as a sin*. If you wish, you could change the second part of the sentence to read *, **regards** that were widely and firmly. . .*; however, that would be awkward because *regards* isn't normally used in that way.

Comment: Then, if "which is" is added as in "which is a view", does "which" still refer to "excessive personal debt is a sin"?

Comment: @SinK Correct. The addition of *which* doesn't change that.

Comment: @SinK I have updated my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: I have got the points exactly you have talked about! Thank you very much. Your answers are professional, clear, and exact as always. Can I ask you one more question that is to do with this question? In this sentence "My mother can juggle five balls at once, which I can't do", can we look at "which" as referring to "juggling five balls at once"? Is it strange to see "which" as including "my mother" ? I really want to know.

Comment: @SinK Yes, that's how it would be interpreted. *My mother can **[X]**, which I can't do.* Because of the use of *can* and *can't* generating a mostly parallel structure, it's assumed that *which* stands in for *[X]*. Another way of writing the sentence would be the following: *My mother can **[X]**, but I can't **[X]**.*

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you help me once again if you're not busy now? I think you have a good answer for this question as you're specialized in editing. Link : https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/221425/the-position-of-which